# analogues of power sum polynomials for symmetric Laurent polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions, laurent-polynomials, root-systems

To deal with root systems of type B C D, one needs to understand symmetric Laurent polynomials $\Lambda$. I am wondering if the naive definition of power sum symmetric Laurent polynomials form a basis in $\Lambda$. More specifically, define 
$$ p_r = \sum_{i=1}^N x_i^r + x_i^{-r},$$
and define power sum symmetric Laurent polynomial indexed by a partition $\lambda \vdash n$ as
$$ p_\lambda = \prod_{j=1}^n p_{\lambda_i}.$$
What are some standard references that talk about the connection of $\Lambda$ with root systems, as well as Macdonald operators? Thanks.

edit: I guess it is obvious that $p_\lambda$ does form a basis, if I restrict to symmetric Laurent polynomials that are also symmetric with respect to $x_i \mapsto x_i^{-1}$. So I would like to change my question to just asking for a reference relating $\Lambda$ with Macdonald operators.

Comment: Hi! If I am not mistaken your question is related to mine(though I am working with type A instead of B,C,D at this stage):

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/87939/reference-request-basis-in-terms-of-ring-of-symmetric-polynomials

Comment: Yes I think Fulton Harris has some stuff about Laurent polynomials, but not as extensively as Macdonald's book.

Comment: You mean this one:http://www.amazon.com/Symmetric-Functions-Polynomials-Mathematical-Monographs/dp/0198504500/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1329267605&sr=8-1?

Comment: Yes. I think you will find most of the stuff known about symmetric polynomials in that book. It's surprising that the analogous theory for Laurent symmetric polynomials aren't developed in monograph form.

Comment: Hi! I think you may find it interesting to look up resources related to Konstant polynomial. Personally I do not know very much about Macdonald operators/polynomial but it is nice to know. I also found his book. Thank you. 

Comment: @Changwei: thanks a lot! I never knew it had a name.

Comment: @John Jiang: I think this is well-known to the experts in Lie theory and index theory. There are numerous references available. I am just a novice in the field. 

Comment: A friend of mine just told me that Laurent symmetric polynomials are simple symmetric polynomials in the variables $\xi_i:=(x_i+ x_i^{-1})$. So this is completely isomorphic to $\Lambda_n$.

Comment: @John Jiang: Yes, this is very clear from the start. Also this article may be relevant to your question:

http://www.math.washington.edu/~billey/papers/classical.ps

Comment: @Changwei, Thanks for your reference. I wonder why it is necessary to introduce the circled variables instead of just using Laurent expansion in the paper. Also even though symmetric Laurent is completely isomorphic to $\Lambda_n$, the action of the analogue of macdonald operator on them will be very different.

Comment: @John Jiang: I cannot really read this paper, but I see what you meant. Thanks. 